# Cannot Read packageName ':generateDebugBuildConfig'

Tags: android, build.gradle

I have an issue where my build cannot read my package name. I've checked everything and it seems fine, but I don't know why it's not finding the package.

The directory it's pointing to for `AndroidManifest.xml` is wrong:

"`/Users/tonystark/Documents/GitHub/roboapp/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`"

It should be:

"`/Users/tonystark/Documents/GitHub/roboapp/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`"

I'm not sure if my debug is working correctly. I've tried changing the build variant to debug but that wasn't the issue. I've also moved the `src` folder containing the `AndroidManifest.xml` to the `/roboapp/` folder, but there were more errors so that was wrong.

build.gradle:

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 28
  buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
  defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.example.roboapp"
      minSdkVersion 22
      targetSdkVersion 28
      versionCode 1
      versionName "1.0"
     }
  }

 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/toolbar_show_addresses_simple"
  style="@style/toolbar_dark"
  package="com.example.roboapp">
```

ERROR:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':generateDebugBuildConfig'.

  > Cannot read packageName from /Users/tonystark/Documents/GitHub/roboapp/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

I have also tried deleting the cache to no avail.

Comment: have you rename your package name ?

Comment: The name is “roboapp”, nothing works for me. I may just have to move everything to a new project and go clean without resvolving.