# Failed to query the value of property 'packageName'. Manifest file does not exist:

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

EDIT: Workaround

I can build my app using `./gradlew :app:assembleRelease` but this isn't actually fixing the issue it is only a workaround. After that I find the apk in `/app/build/outputs/apk/release` and sign the apk manually in the terminal using `apksigner`. If anyone is reading this: and no solution to this problem is found, this is a workaround that works (although it isn't a solution). To sign the apk manually, search for "Build your app from the command line" and a Android developers page explaining how to do this should come up.

---

Every time I try to build, it does ":generateDebugBuildConfig" instead of "app:generateDebugBuildConfig".

```
Execution failed for task ':generateDebugBuildConfig'.
> Failed to calculate the value of task ':generateDebugBuildConfig' property 'buildConfigPackageName'.
   > Failed to query the value of property 'packageName'.
      > Manifest file does not exist: /home/android-studio/Documents/your_android_app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
```

This issue seems to be the exact same as this one :

[Cannot Read packageName ':generateDebugBuildConfig'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55467012/cannot-read-packagename-generatedebugbuildconfig)

Yet that got no answer.

The manifest file points to the wrong direction:

/home/android-studio/Documents/your_android_app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

instead of

/home/android-studio/Documents/your_android_app/**app**/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

This is caused by the fact that build runs ":generateDebugBuildConfig" instead of ":app:generateDebugBuildConfig"

I cannot find anything about this on the internet except the issue I linked to (which had no solution).

[It is NOT THIS BUG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424135/android-studio-android-manifest-doesnt-exists-or-has-incorrect-root-tag), that one shows up in the graphical UI while this one shows up in the build output. (Plus I tried most of the solutions there, they all didn't work).

Furthermore, I can run my app perfectly fine, seems like I can run the module "app" and this fixes the issue.

[Image showing the run configurations that do not apply to build for some reason](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQcAq.png)

I cannot do this for Build at all, and therefore I cannot use it. The problem with this is I cannot generate a signed apk if the build doesn't work.

Thanks for all the help.

EDIT:

build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-parcelize'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mapitall.SwiftAddress"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.0.1"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.20"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io"}
    }
}
```

build.gradle (app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mapitall.SwiftAddress"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.0.1"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.21"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.1.8'
    implementation 'com.github.MKergall:osmbonuspack:6.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mapitall.SwiftAddress"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="0.1">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.KeypadMapper4">
        <activity android:name="com.mapitall.SwiftAddress.ChooseBackgroundImagery" />
        <activity android:name="com.mapitall.SwiftAddress.Keypad" />
        <activity android:name="com.mapitall.SwiftAddress.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the stacktrace after trying to build the app in terminal using gradle:

```
> Task :generateDebugBuildConfig FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':generateDebugBuildConfig'.
> Failed to calculate the value of task ':generateDebugBuildConfig' property 'buildConfigPackageName'.
   > Failed to query the value of property 'packageName'.
      > Manifest file does not exist: /home/android-studio/Documents/SwiftAddress2/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':generateDebugBuildConfig'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:38)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:409)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:399)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:242)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:150)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:94)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:356)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty$PropertyQueryException: Failed to calculate the value of task ':generateDebugBuildConfig' property 'buildConfigPackageName'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.finalizeNow(AbstractProperty.java:239)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.beforeRead(AbstractProperty.java:230)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.calculatePresence(AbstractProperty.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.isPresent(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:74)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.bean.AbstractNestedRuntimeBeanNode$BeanPropertyValue.call(AbstractNestedRuntimeBeanNode.java:137)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.AbstractValidatingProperty.validate(AbstractValidatingProperty.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.DefaultTaskProperties.validate(DefaultTaskProperties.java:193)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.validate(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:506)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:39)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:28)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:194)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:186)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:114)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:409)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:399)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:242)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:150)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:94)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:356)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty$PropertyQueryException: Failed to query the value of property 'packageName'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.doCalculateValue(AbstractProperty.java:136)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.calculateOwnValue(AbstractProperty.java:127)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.calculateValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:103)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.withFinalValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:151)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultProperty.finalValue(DefaultProperty.java:133)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultProperty.finalValue(DefaultProperty.java:25)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.finalizeNow(AbstractProperty.java:236)
        ... 46 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: Manifest file does not exist: /home/android-studio/Documents/SwiftAddress2/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
        at com.android.builder.errors.IssueReporter.reportError(IssueReporter.kt:106)
        at com.android.builder.errors.IssueReporter.reportError$default(IssueReporter.kt:102)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.manifest.LazyManifestParserKt.parseManifest(LazyManifestParser.kt:91)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.manifest.LazyManifestParserKt.access$parseManifest(LazyManifestParser.kt:1)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.manifest.LazyManifestParser$manifestData$2$provider$1.transform(LazyManifestParser.kt:47)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.manifest.LazyManifestParser$manifestData$2$provider$1.transform(LazyManifestParser.kt:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.TransformBackedProvider.mapValue(TransformBackedProvider.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.TransformBackedProvider.calculateOwnValue(TransformBackedProvider.java:65)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.calculateValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:103)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.MappingProvider.calculateOwnValue(MappingProvider.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.calculateValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:103)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.withFinalValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:151)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultProperty.finalValue(DefaultProperty.java:133)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultProperty.finalValue(DefaultProperty.java:25)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.finalizeNow(AbstractProperty.java:236)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.beforeRead(AbstractProperty.java:230)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.calculateOwnValue(AbstractProperty.java:126)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.calculateValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:103)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.TransformBackedProvider.calculateOwnValue(TransformBackedProvider.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.calculateValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:103)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.MappingProvider.calculateOwnValue(MappingProvider.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.calculateValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:103)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultProperty.calculateValueFrom(DefaultProperty.java:128)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultProperty.calculateValueFrom(DefaultProperty.java:25)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.doCalculateValue(AbstractProperty.java:133)
        ... 52 more
```

Comment: Can you add manifest.xml file and .gradle file (root + app project)

Comment: I added both the build.gradle s and the Androidmanifest.xml

Comment: is there any solutions? I tried cloning the repo again into a seperate folder from my github repo, that didn't fix the bug. I would really appreciate any help

Comment: I can build my app using `./gradlew :app:assembleRelease` but this isn't actually fixing the issue it is only a workaround. After that I find the apk in `/app/build/outputs` and sign the apk manually in the terminal using `apksigner`. If anyone is reading this: and no solution to this problem is found, this is a workaround that works (although it isn't a solution). To sign the apk manually, search for "Build your app from the command line" and a Android developers page explaining how to do this should come up.

Comment: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVnRd.jpg) you can change edit configurations

Comment: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVnRd.jpg) you can change edit configurations

Answer (score -1):

In the first code that you attached ( build.gradle  from  root configuration). There is an android configuration.Try to remove that, I mean that file should be contains only :

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.20"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io"}
    }
}
```

Also,  try to clean de project with the following command, or just with clean option from android studio:

```
./gradlew clean
```

Finally,  verify if this project had another package name? or you have changed that package name?

Notes:

If this repository is public, attach it for better debugging.

Comment: `Cause: compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle`

Comment: what is the solution to this? This is what happens when I remove the `android{}` clause from the main build.gradle

Comment: This doesn't actually fix the issue. When syncing the gradle in android studio, it gives me two warnings: `compileSdkVersion not specified` and `Manifest File does not exist`.

Comment: Github repo: https://github.com/IpswichMapper/SwiftAddress

Comment: Hello, I can run the application without problems

Comment: Can you try, to invalid cache and restart option from android studio?

Comment: What do you mean by "run application without problems"? I can do this also, pressing the "run" button when the "run configuration" is "app" works fine. HOWEVER, the "Make Project" option doesn't work. This option is required if you want to build a signed apk in Android studio. Can you try building a signed apk?

Comment: I've done invalidate cache and restart. That didn't work. Yes, I can "run" it fine, but I can't build it so I can't make signed apks in Android studio. I have to use a workaround (which is listed at the top of the question now.

Comment: what is your output when you press the "build" button? Thanks for the help